# Nullement ou aucunement ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, adverbes, synonymes

Apparement, ils sont synonymes, mais je me demande s'il y a une subtile différence entre eux ? Ou peut-être qu'ils sont totalement interchangeable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (TLFi) [**nullement**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nullement) [Correspond à nul I A] Pas du tout, en aucune façon. Synon. **aucunement**.

(TLFi) [**nul I A**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nul) I. − Adjectif
A. − Adj. indéf. (Ne) ... nul(l)e + subst.[Accompagnant un subst. en position suj. ou en position compl.; marque une exclusion totale] Pas un. Synon. **aucun**.

> (TLFi) [**aucunement**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aucunement) II.− Usuel. [Construit avec ne ou sans] Nullement, du tout, d'aucune manière.

Les deux sont employés en corrélation avec « ne » à un temps personnel ou non. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&content=Il+n%27est+aucunement%2CIl+n%27est+nullement&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIl%20n%27est%20aucunement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIl%20n%27est%20nullement%3B%2Cc0)). Cependant la tournure impersonnelle « Il n'est nullement… » est beaucoup plus courante et apparemment c'est le choix préféré dans la langue parlée ; « Il n'est aucunement » se trouve plus dans la vieille langue et a quelque chose de plus formel; néanmoins on l'écrit toujours. De nos jours les deux sont beaucoup remplacés par « pas du tout ».

- Il n'est *nullement* question de passer par là.
- Il n'est *pas du tout* question de passer par là.

Les deux sont employés en corrélation avec « sans ». ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sans+aucunement%2Csans+nullement&corpus=19&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csans%20aucunement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20nullement%3B%2Cc0))

La seule différence semble se trouver dans l'usage; « nullement » serait plus moderne.

Comment: Voilà, merci comme toujours pour tous les détails !

Answer (score 2):

Le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aucunement/6371) dit qu'il y a une légère différence de registre, qu'"aucunement" est plus familier que "nullement." En termes de sens, ils sont totalement interchangeables.